# Implementing Map in C with only <stdio.h> and <malloc.h>

Tags: c, algorithm, dictionary, time-complexity

I am required to implement `Map` in `C` within limitations of standard library. I can only include `<stdio.h>` and `<malloc.h>`. I have implemented a linear version with array `(complexity = O(N^2))` and with BST on map key, `(complexity = O(Nlog(N))`. I wonder is there any other better option. I was looking for an approach for competitive programming where implementation time is an issue.

When key is `int` type, we can simply use an array of `value` with `int` key, but when key is of different type (for example `string` or `struct`) how efficiently we can make this map. That's what i want.

My linear implementation:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>

typedef struct _key{
    int k; // can be anything
} key;

typedef struct _value{
    int v; // can be anything
} value;

int count = 0;
key keys[1000];
value map[1000];

int getIndex(key k){

    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){
        if(keys[i].k == k)
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}

void put(key k, value v){

    int p = getIndex(k);

    if(p >= 0){
        map[p] = v;
    }
    else{
        keys[count] = k;
        map[count] = v;
        count++;
    }
}

value get(key k){

    value empty;
    empty.v = -1;

    int p = getIndex(k);

    if(p >= 0){
        return map[p];
    }
    else{
        return empty;
    }
}

int main(){

    key k;
    value v;

    k.k = 2;
    v.v = 5;

    put(k, v);

    v = get(k);

    printf("key: %d value: %d\n", k.k, v.v);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Show your code..

Comment: It's certainly possible to implement a hash table from scratch in C, but it's not clear what exactly you are asking.

Comment: @surjit Please look into my array implementation

Comment: @JohnBollinger When key is int we can simply use a array of value with int key, but when key is of different type (for example string or struct) how efficiently we can make this hash. Thats what i want..

Comment: A hash table should somewhere have a hash function.

Comment: @FelixPalmen actually I meant map, not hashmap. I changed my question. please help.

Comment: @SazzadHissainKhan well as your question was about efficiency, a *real* hashtable wouldn't be a bad idea. Here's [my generic approach](https://github.com/Zirias/pocas/blob/master/src/lib/core/hashtable.c) in case you're interested -- it's not all *that* much code.

Comment: If this is working code, would this question be better on https://codereview.stackexchange.com?

Comment: @AShelly indeed.

Comment: @AShelly I am not reviewing my code, I was looking for an implementation. Posted the code because a Surjit wanted to see the code. Also I have no experience on condereview.stack link

Comment: @SazzadHissainKhan you *have* a working implementation and are looking for ways to do it better/more efficient/... I'd say this qualifies as review request.

Comment: @FelixPalmen My code is just a naive impl i am sure. I want to know the efficient approach or algorithm 1st. I guess there must be better algorithm then O(N^2) which will have nothing with my current code.

Comment: @surjit can you help now?

Comment: When someone asks a question without code, we complain. When they add code, we say it's a review request. Give the guy a break.

Comment: @SazzadHissainKhan yes, a *real* hashtable. In theory, this has `O(1)` access (and it *has* in practice as long as it's collision free) -- the hash function itself will probably depend on the size of the hash key, but that's not your `n` here (doesn't change with the number of items in the table)

Comment: @m69 well you see there's no answer yet. The situation is more that of a review (aka *what could I do better implementing this*) ... He doesn't have an actual problem with his code but is looking for more general advice and indeed, this might be better placed on the codereview site.

Comment: @m69 In this case it seems like OP is just asking for an implementation of a very-well-known data structure, of which there are many already available online. IMO the best case scenario here is posting their working implementation to code review, any version of this question posted here would either be unclear/too broad/off topic or would just be adding to the noise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the best implementations of a map ADT is a hashtable, for which lookup is constant-time (`O(1)`) if you have a good hash function and a large enough bucket array. There are several existing implementations for such, but they can be implemented fairly easily yourself if that is required. Simply select a hash function for your needs and use something like the following (WLAG, let's assume your key is of type `KEY`, value is of type `VALUE` and hash function prototype `unsigned char hash(KEY)`, with a key comparison function `int keykmp(KEY,KEY)` returning zero if and only if the two arguments are 'equal'  [hash table here has 256 entries, or 1 KiB memory overhead on a 32-bit system; you could use more]):

```
typedef struct bucket {
    KEY key
    VALUE val;
    struct bucket * next;
} bucket;

bucket * table[256];

void add(KEY key, VALUE val) {
    bucket * entry;
    unsigned char hashval = hash(key);

    if(table[hashval] == NULL) {
        entry = table[hashval] = (bucket*) malloc(sizeof(bucket);
    } else {
        entry = table[hashval];
        while(entry->next != NULL) entry = entry->next;
        entry->next = (bucket*) malloc(sizeof(bucket);
        entry = entry->next;
    }

    entry->key = key;
    entry->val = val;
    entry->next = NULL;
}

VALUE lookup(KEY key) {
    bucket * entry;

    for (entry = table[hash(key)]; entry != NULL; entry = entry->next) {
        if(keykmp(key, entry->key) == 0) return entry->value;
    }

    return NULL; /* Or whatever other error value */
}
```

Comment: Great. I got the idea. Thanks i will try.